# How to use same view.tpl for some taxonomy terms

Tags: views

I have few taxonomy terms (taxonomy/term/1 taxonomy/term/2 ...etc ).
Every of that term has a different view.

I want to be able to use the same views-view--[myview]--page.tpl.php for more than one view.

The easiest way is just to copy the file and  alter the myview name to be the same of the each view.

Is another solution?

I use different taxonomy views because i have a FILTER CRITERIA of Taxonomy term: Parent term (= x) for every one.

Example:
taxonomy/term/1 has Taxonomy term: Parent term (= 1) to show all taxonomy terms that is child of taxonomy term 1.

Drupal 7

Comment: You don't need to create a new view for that. Just add a new display. You can configure many pages, blocks and other stuff in one view.

Comment: @jack-pl : I tried but when i created a new page (taxonomy/term/2) from my taxonomy 1 view the taxonomy/term/2 page work nice but the taxonomy/term/1 page show the same content with the ../term/2 page.  Probable because i have a filter criteria of parent term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try and error and for the hint  Jack-PL tell me i figure this out.

I make a new view with taxonomy terms. I set the Field (taxonomy name and taxonomy id) .Contexual filters i set the Taxonomy term: Parent term >Provide default value>Taxonomy term id from url.

So know i only have to use Displays >Add>Page>And that did the trick!

Now i can theme with one tpl all the taxonomy pages!